# Store location information from a tweet

Tags: twitter, download, location, monitor

I want to download tweets to my own database. I want to give the #subject in the script and then download the latest tweets. I want to do this with php

i can only find websites where you can monitor it but i need a script. Does anyone knows one?

Important is that i can download the message, author and location.
I am not familiar with twitter so i am not sure if this is possible.

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: "I want to give the #subject in the script". Do you mean you want to give the query and get the results depending on the keyword(s) you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would involve using the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) which is implemented as a RESTful web service. Mainly you would be using the [Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search).

**Using the Twitter API and Search API**:
The first thing you need is your search query, if you don't already know it then use the [search page](http://twitter.com/search). Take the end of the search URL and use that as the parameter for the search API. For example a search for the hashtag #stackoverflow gives us the following URL.

```
http://twitter.com/#!/search/%23stackoverflow
```

The query for the search API would then look like this.

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23stackoverflow
```

The URL above returns a JSON response which you can parse and use in your PHP script.

**Parsing the search with PHP:**
This script interfaces with the Twitter API and prints the results, storing the results is an exercise left to the reader:

```
<?php
class Twitter {
    public function __construct() {  }
    public function searchResults( $query = null ) {
        $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" . urlencode($query);
        $curl = curl_init();

        // cURL options for the current session.
        $options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
                      );
        // If all the options are set correctly then fetch and parse the results.
            if (curl_setopt_array($curl, $options)) {
                // Execute cURL and store the returned string.
                $json_search_results = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close( $curl );
                // Decode the JSON string returned by cURL.
                $search_results = json_decode($json_search_results);
                return $search_results;
            }
    }
}

// Searching Twittter using the new class.
$Twitter = new Twitter();
$search = Twitter::searchResults("#stackoverflow");
var_dump($search);
?>
```

The output of the script:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (11) {
  ["completed_in"]=>
  float(0.137)
  ["max_id"]=>
  int(179961163788976129)
  ["max_id_str"]=>
  string(18) "179961163788976129"
  ["next_page"]=>
  string(52) "?page=2&max_id=179961163788976129&q=%23stackoverflow"
  ["page"]=>
  int(1)
  ["query"]=>
  string(16) "%23stackoverflow"
  ["refresh_url"]=>
  string(47) "?since_id=179961163788976129&q=%23stackoverflow"
  ["results"]=>
  array(15) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (18) {
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(31) "Wed, 14 Mar 2012 16:04:19 +0000"
      ["from_user"]=>
      string(7) "kel666_"
      ["from_user_id"]=>
      int(55252171)
      ["from_user_id_str"]=>
      string(8) "55252171"
      ["from_user_name"]=>
      string(14) "Fabio Spinelli"
      ["geo"]=>
      NULL
      ["id"]=>
      int(179961163788976129)
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(18) "179961163788976129"
      ["iso_language_code"]=>
      string(2) "it"
      ["metadata"]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
        ["result_type"]=>
        string(6) "recent"
      }
      ["profile_image_url"]=>
      string(71) "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/585239857/n571218917_3111_normal.jpg"
      ["profile_image_url_https"]=>
      string(73) "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/585239857/n571218917_3111_normal.jpg"
      ["source"]=>
      string(59) "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;"
      ["text"]=>
      string(114) "postare domande su #stackoverflow Ã¨ fico perchÃ© c'Ã¨ sempre pronto qualcuno a cazziarti o cmq a far la maestrina"
      ["to_user"]=>
      NULL
      ["to_user_id"]=>
      NULL
      ["to_user_id_str"]=>
      NULL
      ["to_user_name"]=>
      NULL
    }
  // Snip.
  ["results_per_page"]=>
  int(15)
  ["since_id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["since_id_str"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```